Using Azure Logic Apps to validate excel documents and move them to different folders in Sharepoint?
It's been a while since I used Azure Logic Apps but I've got a use case for a client where we need a (stage) landing place for excel data (probably sharepoint) but before we ingest that data into our Snowflake database we need to validate that the excel spreadsheet has met certain validation rules. For example, only certain values in certain columns, etc. Is there any functionality within Azure Logic Apps which could handle something like this? Or would we need a python script (or something of the like) to be called to do the validation step before moving the file to a new folder for it to be picked up by our data ingestion tool?

Nothing prevents you from reading data from Excel using the relevant connector but if these rules are going to have any degree of complexity my recommendation would be to do validation Azure Functions using Python. So you can use a Logic App for the overall workflow management but have that Logic App call an Azure Function and send it either data or a path to the file in blob storage to validate it.

I do agree with @KonTheCat, but in Logic apps you can use below design:

After getting sharepoint excel file, you can parse the json that you got and later send it in condition, with which you can check the condition, if it has your condition then you can do next steps, otherwise it goes to false. For further you can refer to get data from excel.
Parse Json helps you to get column and values and then test the condition. Alternatively as @KonTheCat mentioned you can use Azure Functions if complexity is more.
Below I checked Name column contains  value "Rithwik" like below:

Output:


Ok, this is helpful, but what do you mean by parse json? We wouldn't have any json be sent in. The excel file(s) would be dropped/uploaded into a specific folder by a user (or number of users) so I assume the same functionality is available without the json piece?

No excel file list rows present in table gives us output in json format in logic apps
